# PHP error Warning: Unknown(includes/main.php)

Tags: php, html

Web page contains php includes:

```
<?php
  include 'http://www.example.com/header.txt';
?>
```

and

```
<?php
  include 'http://www.example.com/footer.txt';
?>
```

`header.txt` and `footer.txt` files with html markup are placed in the root folder of a website.

Everything went ok pretty long, but suddenly the following error messages appeared on webpages in browser right after markup areas, incerted by these php scripts:

> Warning: Unknown(includes/main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in >Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown(includes/main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in >Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: (null)(): Failed opening 'includes/main.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

All markup from txt files is shown by browser correctly. The only problem are these **Warning messages**. Site is hosted on shared hosting. Nothing was changed in the content of web site folder before these messages appeared.

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any `auto_prepend` or `auto_append` directives? And btw: prevent `include`'s over HTTP if you can, a local file or possibly a mounted share is _extremely_ faster & more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the site url to include the files which is not ideal and depends on php settings eg `allow_url_fopen`; it won't work either if you move your site to some different domain. Try using relative paths instead, example:

```
include 'includes/header.txt';
```